# Añadir nueva columna que coja campo de siguiente fila python

Tags: python

Estoy empezando con python y tendria el siguiente data frame

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear una nueva Columna 3 que coja el valor siguiente de Columna 1 cuando recorra Columna 2 y encuentra Andar como resultado seria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
df.loc[:, "Columna 3"] = df.loc[df'Columna 2'] == 'Andar','Columna 1'].iloc[1]
```

Esto me da como resultado toda la Columna 3 = Manuel

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Columna 1': ['Juan', 'Pepe', 'Manuel', 'Antonio', 'Miguel', 'Juan', 'Antonio'], 'Columna 2' ['Correr','Andar','Andar','Saltar', 'Andar', 'Saltar', 'Correr']})

print (df)

df['Columna 3'] = df.loc[df['Columna 2'].shift(1)== 'Andar', 'Columna 1']
df['Columna 3'] = df['Columna 3'].shift(-1).fillna('')

print (df)
```

Comment: Una respuesta sin explicación es un puro acto de magia. Incluso si soluciona el problema, nadie puede aprender nada de ella.

Comment: Gracias por su recomendación y ayuda muy amable